# How can I create a new user for a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to create users that I can add to groups on my site, but I just can't figure out how to create a new user, all I can find is how to add an already existing user.
Please help me.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this should be on superuser i'd have thought ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is done through Active Directory, so create the user in Active directory, then add the user to the Site.

There is a Server admin process in sharepoint (see your central admin site) that updates the list in SharePoint, from Active Directory.

Comment: Thanx for the answer but I can't find the tab you are talking about, you know the server admin process one, if you don't mind can you explain it step by step.
Thanx a million

Comment: Ok, if you go to Central admin -> Application Management -> Authentication Providers, click Windows you'll be able to see where the settings are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new active directory user is done my running the import task on the Share Services provider in the SharePoint Central Admin. Normally this is automatically scheduled to run at night.

I believe that controlling the Active directory import can only be done with the SharePoint **Server** version and not with the (free) WSS 3.0 version (aka SharePoint **Services**).